# ASP.NET MVC Master Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

How can one do this?

I would like to save the master pages template in the database and then based on a query string pull the correct template.

Is this possible?

Comment: You want to store the template in the database, or you want to store a record of which template a particular page should be using?

Comment: The template which will contain the content place holders etc...

Answer (score 1):

This article by Phil Haack may be of some help to you:

**Scripting ASP.NET MVC Views Stored In The Database**

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/22/scripted-db-views.aspx

It's not directly related to Master Pages however the concepts Phil talks about and uses in his article could be just what you're looking for.

Comment: I can render the template fine but, the content place holder controls are being abit more ticky any ideas?